# Countability of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ using isomorphism with $\Bbb Z[i]$ - how to make this rigorous?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, gaussian-integers

> Visualise the set $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$  as points on the complex plane,  and take origin as the center of a circle of radius $r$. With $r$ going from $0$ to $\infty$ - as you encounter points on the circle, write them down in counterclockwise order. This way you have a bijective mapping, thus $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ is countable.

This proof about the countability of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ doesn't look **rigorous enough to me.** It was proposed by one of my colleagues. The proposal is to write down elements of $Z[i]$ as we encounter them in some sort of a spiral order.

I need help making this more **rigorous**.

Is there an **explicit bijection** for this? It'd be great if someone could help me construct the same.

Perhaps we must show that every such circle has only a countable number of such points and that only countably many such circles, i.e. values of $r$ matter. Thanks!

Comment: Well of course "write them down in counter-clockwise order" isn't rigorous. What you want to do, is take $B_n = \{(x, y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2 : \max(|x|, |y|) = n\}$ and order $B_n$ in a "counter-clockwise" manner.

Comment: What would the explicit bijection give you that the argument above would not? To make the idea behind the argument more apparent, try constructing such a bijection $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ using lex order.

Comment: @Jakobian Could you elaborate?

Comment: @anomaly Rigor.

Comment: can you use countability of $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$?

Comment: @SK19 Yes, that has been proved earlier. How will you use it in this proof?

Comment: Geometrically... that'd be next to impossible to formalize. Also it provides no argument why the result would be  countable (it just assumes its reasonable).  What if you hit a spot for some $r$ there is stretch of angles wnere between any two angles no matter how slim you wil find a complex nubmer with integers and there is none that come first.  Why shouldn't that happen.  I'd say walk away from this.

Comment: Okay it's pretty clear the first radius is $r =1$ and and the next is $\sqrt 2$ but and $r = \sqrt{n^2 + m^2}$ we be a valid radius if you have one $n^2 + m^2$ how do you know what the next such $r$ will be.   what's the next $r$ after $r = \sqrt{235^2 + 5879^2}$?

Comment: I was going for a countability argument using $(n,m) \rightarrow \sqrt{n^2+m^2}$ being surjective onto it's range, but I think strawberry-sunshine made a better argument already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this - does it look fine enough?

Consider $z = x+iy \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, with $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.  As $r^2$ goes from zero to $\infty$, we cover the entire complex plane. If $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $r^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Define $P = \{ r^2: r\in \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}, r^2 \in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable,  so is $P$. Now, for some fixed $r_1$such that $r_1^2\in P$, think about $x^2 + y^2 = r_1^2$. This gives $|x| \le r_1, |y| \le r_1$. Since $r_1$ is finite, the set of values $(x,y) $ such that  $x^2 + y^2 = r_1^2$ holds, is finite. Knowing that a countable union of countable sets is countable, we see that the set $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is countable. As a result, $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is also countable.

Comment: The is good and that is how to do it.  But "Knowing that a countable union of countable sets is countable"  How do you know that?  If you know that then $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z = \cup_{z\in Z}( \{z\}\times \mathbb Z)$ is countable.  Isn't that a much simpler argument.  Your argument still doesn't give you the bijection (if that is what is important to you).  "does it look fine enough?" fine enough for what exactly.

Comment: Fine enough as a proof. Also your idea is great, I could've used "countable union of countable sets is countable" in a much simpler way. Thanks for that :)

Comment: it is not even needed, as "countable union of finite sets is countable" is enough, which might be more intuitive :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to strawberry-sunshine's answer: An explicit bijection is hard because it is hard (a) to give an explicit enumeration of all radii that contain a number from $\mathbb Z [i]$ and (b) given one such radius to enumerate all numbers in $\mathbb Z [i]$ with that radius with an explicit function.

As the other answer pointed out, for any radius $r$ there is a finite number of associated numbers in $\mathbb Z [i]$, say S. We can order these formally counterclockwise by first ordering all the numbers $S_+$ from the upper half plane (plus the nonnegative real number halfline) by setting $S_0 = \emptyset$, $S_n=\{a_1+ib_1,\ldots,a_n+ib_n\}$ and

$$a_{n+1} = \max \{a\in \mathbb R: \exists b\in \mathbb R: a+bi\in S_+\setminus S_n\}, \quad b_{n+1} = \sqrt{r^2-a_{n+1}^2} $$

and after that, if $r\neq 0$, set $a_{|S_+|+n} = a_{|S_+|-n+1}$ and $b_{|S_+|+n} = -b_{|S_+|-n+1}$. So by induction, you can order all those numbers counterclockwise, but a convenient definition without using recursion escapes me.

---

However, this is all unneededly complicated. Also the line

> Visualise the set $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ as points on the complex plane

basically already is a bijection, namely $f:\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z[i], (a,b)\mapsto a+bi$. If you are looking for formal proofs always be suspicious when someone uses terms like "visualize", as that is not a valid concept in formal proofs. The given bijection can easily be seen as bijective by confirming the function $g:\mathbb Z[i]\rightarrow \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z, z\mapsto (\Re(z),\Im(z))$ is the inverse (which we can check by checking that $g\circ f$ and $f \circ g$ are the identities on $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z[i]$ respectively). Therefore, the enumerating as done above with the counterclockwise ordering is unneededly contrived, albeit a good thought exercise nonetheless.

---

Finally a way I would prefer is simply using that if $|A|=|C|$ and $|B|=|D|$ (i.e. bijections between these sets $A, B, C, D$ exist), then $|A\times B|=|C\times D|$ (if the given bijections are $f$ and $g$ respectively, then the new bijection is given by $(a,c)\mapsto (f(a),g(c))$). Then set $A=B=\mathbb N$ and $C=D=\mathbb Z$ and the countability of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ follows from the countability of $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

As the the radius of the circle goes to infinity, each $a+bi$ lies on some circle in the same place as the point $(a,b)$ on the Cartesian graph in $\mathbb{Z}$. I guess there might be a way to explicitly find the radii (which are the going to be same for each point $(a,b)$ in the cartesian plane to the $a+bi$ in the complex plane) and do something with that, but that just seems to make the argument longer. Maybe the point is that this same circle process can be repeated on the Cartesian graph to get that the exact same thing happens.

However, this argument seems to overcomplicate the whole thing by turning this discrete problem into one involving a continuous process of taking $r \to \infty$. It really seems to be saying the same thing as the explicit bijection, but with more words and unnecessary ideas. Perhaps I am missing something.